# Relationship between AWS EC2 VPC and Xen Networking

Tags: virtual-machine, amazon-ec2, xen

Does characteristics of networking configuration on AWS VPC (public IP, private IP, subnets, route and gateway) are derived of Xen networking model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The actual [hypervisor is **KVM-based**](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/11/07/aws_writes_new_kvm_based_hypervisor_to_make_its_cloud_go_faster/), not Xen-based.
- The EC2 platform is based on [**AWS Nitro**](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/nitro/) architecture which provides HW abstraction, security, etc.
- The **VPC network is routed** (not switched) and spans across multiple nodes. It has nothing to do with KVM or Xen networking that are local to the VM host.

Not sure what exactly you’re asking about. If you have any specific features or limitations of EC2 or Xen networking in mind please be more specific.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank very much for your answer! Your third point is exactly the response for my doubt. AWS EC2 as well as Oracle Cloud Computing has networking configuration very similar, where public IP is not associated directly to instance. I thought that this fact was derived from some Xen networking model.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.